# can not save multiuser execution setting for chrome plugin in registry under key while installing OATS

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to install OATS12.5 in my machine but I'm getting can not save multi user execution setting for chrome plugin in registry under key "HKLM\software\Mozilla Plugins\@oracle.com\Openscriptplugin"
Fist time when I have tried I have chrome,mozilla,IE11 in my machine later I have uninstalled chrome n Mozilla n IE11 n installed IE8 still same issue..
could you please tell me is it browser issue or any other issue n I couldn't see add-ons in IE after installing OATS.can someone help me...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error "cannot save multiuser execution setting for chrome plugin in registry" during execution of install-openscript.bat (12.5.0.2) in Windows 7.

It only worked when I ran it as administrator in windows:

1. right-click on CMD icon and choose "Run as administrator"
2. now run command: install-openscript.bat